# DC/DC Booster to 5v 500ma?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, lipo, dip

I'm trying to find a circuit capable of boosting a normal alkaline battery or maybe a li-po to 5V/500mA. I want a through hole IC to try it on the breadboard.

V<sub>in</sub> could be 2.5V (or lower) and maximum 3.7V.

Is there any DIP package capable of doing that? A diagram would be appreciated too.

Comment: Did you google for 'step up converter ic'?

Comment: There seems to be quite a few TH IC if you search on digikey (http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?FV=fff40027%2Cfff8029a%2C1140050%2C2040001%2C2040002%2C2040006%2C2040007%2C2040008%2C204000d%2C204000f%2C2040011%2C2040012%2C2040014%2C2040015%2C204003c%2C2040050%2C2040068%2C2040069%2C204007c%2C204007f%2C204008f%2C20400aa%2C20400f4%2C2040117%2C204011b%2C204020c%2C2dc11f5%2C2dc1201%2C2dc122f%2C2dc126d%2C2dc128b%2C2dc128c%2C2dc1376&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=127&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0)

Comment: Insisting of thru hole will severly limit the possibilities and is pointless anyway.  In any case, what you want is called a "boost converter".  There are many chips for that, although 500 mA is rather a lot for most of them.

Comment: You can get a boost converter as a module, with 0.1" pins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much most boost converters do what you want. Anything that uses 1 or 2 AA for a usb charger have this.

The [MintyBoost](http://www.ladyada.net/make/mintyboost/parts.html) is a popular (and fully detailed) diy kit for boosting 2 NiMH or Alkaline to 5v at 500mA.

It is based on the dip [LT1302](http://www.linear.com/product/LT1302) with the usual passive components needed.

Comment: Good find dude +1

Answer (score 1):

MC34063 is the best in the market. It has been market leader in the DC-DC boost converter for a long time.Its available in the DIP package.It has following ratings

[image]

The reference design is 
[image]

You can select the component value from the following table of formulas 
[image]

Comment: 3.0v minimum VIN is quite high for 1 or 2 cell nimh/alkaline battery usage.